# Auto pull from GitHub repository on remote DigitalOcean server after push from local machine?

Tags: git, automation, cloud, digital-ocean, githooks

I have a project that I push to a GitHub repository from my local machine. I deploy this project on a DigitalOcean droplet that I currently have to ssh into and do a git pull, then redeploy manually. Is there an easy way to have it auto pull, and then auto build and redploy itself? I have looked into git hooks but couldn't find any clear answers on what I am trying to do. I set up a post-update git hook on my remote machine which just echos a line but I don't know where to check if the line got echoed or not successfully.

Answer (score 4):

The place you'd need to run the Git hooks is on the server side, in the `post-receive`  or `post-update` hook.  However, GitHub doesn't allow you to run arbitrary hooks by default, since that would be a security risk.  Instead, you can use [GitHub's webhooks](https://developer.github.com/webhooks/) to trigger your droplet to perform some action by making a POST request to it.

You could also have some sort of continuous integration set up that would trigger and deploy a build to your droplet automatically.  This is usually how this type of task is managed.

Finally, you can set up a remote name (say, `foo`) that has multiple `remote.foo.url` entries, one of which is GitHub, and one of which is your droplet.  You can then push to both at the same time by using that remote, in which case your `post-receive` or `post-update` hook will trigger on the droplet (since it received the push).  If there's a checkout, you can use `receive.denyCurrentBranch=updateInstead`, which will let you push to the same branch that's already checked out.  See `git-config(1)` for more details.